# Colspan and Rendered not work in SubTable

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have one dataTable with subTable. I use column attributes rendered and colspan  and it's works in dataTable and footer subtable, but not works in the column of subtable.

Here is my dataTable with subTable code:

```
<p:dataTable id="NotificadaSubTable" var="notificada" value="#{relatoriosMB.listaObjeto1}"
                            rendered="#{not empty relatoriosMB.listaObjeto1}"
                            widgetVar="tableClassAnual"
                            emptyMessage="Não existem registros." resizableColumns="true"
                            liveResize="true">  
                            <f:facet name="header">  
                                <h:outputText value="Área Notificada VS Subclassificações" rendered="#{not empty relatoriosMB.listaObjeto1}"/>  
                            </f:facet>  

                            <p:columnGroup type="header">  
                                <p:row>  
                                    <p:column rowspan="2" colspan="3" headerText="Área Notificada" rendered="#{not empty relatoriosMB.listaObjeto1}"/>  
                                    <p:column colspan="#{relatoriosMB.countColumns}" headerText="Subclassificações" rendered="#{not empty relatoriosMB.listaObjeto1}"/>  
                                </p:row>  

                                <p:row>  
                                    <p:column headerText="JAN" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.janeiro}"/> 
                                    <p:column headerText="FEV" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.fevereiro}"/>
                                    <p:column headerText="MAR" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.marco}"/> 
                                    <p:column headerText="ABR" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.abril}"/>
                                    <p:column headerText="MAI" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.maio}"/>
                                    <p:column headerText="JUN" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.junho}"/>
                                    <p:column headerText="JUL" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.julho}"/>
                                    <p:column headerText="AGO" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.agosto}"/>
                                    <p:column headerText="SET" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.setembro}"/>
                                    <p:column headerText="OUT" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.outubro}"/>
                                    <p:column headerText="NOV" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.novembro}"/>
                                    <p:column headerText="DEZ" style="width:50px;text-align: center" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.dezembro}"/>
                                    <p:column headerText="TOTAL" style="width:100px;text-align: center"/>
                                </p:row>  
                            </p:columnGroup>  

                            <p:subTable id="subTableDetalhe" var="detalhe" value="#{notificada.detalhe}">  
                                <f:facet name="header">  
                                    <h:outputText value="#{notificada.objeto}"/>  
                                </f:facet>  
                                <p:column colspan="3" >  
                                    <h:outputText value=" #{detalhe.objeto}"/>  
                                </p:column>  
                                <p:column>  
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{detalhe.janeiro}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.janeiro}"/>  
                                </p:column>  
                                <p:column>  
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{detalhe.fevereiro}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.fevereiro}"/>  
                                </p:column>  
                                <p:column>  
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{detalhe.marco}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.marco}"/>  
                                </p:column>  
                                <p:column>  
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{detalhe.abril}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.abril}"/>  
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>  
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{detalhe.maio}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.maio}"/>  
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>  
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{detalhe.junho}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.junho}"/>  
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>  
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{detalhe.julho}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.julho}"/>  
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>  
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{detalhe.agosto}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.agosto}"/>  
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>  
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{detalhe.setembro}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.setembro}"/>  
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>  
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{detalhe.outubro}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.novembro}"/>  
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>  
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{detalhe.dezembro}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.dezembro}"/>  
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{detalhe.totalLinha}"/>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:columnGroup type="footer">  
                                    <p:row>  
                                        <p:column colspan="3" style="text-align:right" footerText="Total Subclassificações:" />
                                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.janeiro}"
                                            footerText="#{notificada.totalJaneiro}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.janeiro}" />
                                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.fevereiro}"
                                            footerText="#{notificada.totalFevereiro}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.fevereiro}"/>
                                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.marco}"
                                            footerText="#{notificada.totalMarco}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.marco}"/>
                                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.abril}"
                                            footerText="#{notificada.totalAbril}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.abril}"/>
                                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.maio}"
                                            footerText="#{notificada.totalMaio}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.maio}"/>
                                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.junho}"
                                            footerText="#{notificada.totalJunho}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.junho}"/>
                                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.julho}"  
                                            footerText="#{notificada.totalJulho}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.julho}"/>
                                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.agosto}"
                                            footerText="#{notificada.totalAgosto}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.agosto}"/>
                                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.setembro}"
                                            footerText="#{notificada.totalSetembro}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.setembro}"/>
                                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.outubro}"
                                            footerText="#{notificada.totalOutubro}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.outubro}"/>
                                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.novembro}"
                                            footerText="#{notificada.totalNovembro}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.novembro}"/>
                                        <p:column exportable="#{relatoriosMB.dezembro}"
                                            footerText="#{notificada.totalDezembro}" rendered="#{relatoriosMB.dezembro}"/>
                                        <p:column footerText="#{notificada.totalFooter}"/>
                                    </p:row>  
                                </p:columnGroup>  
                            </p:subTable>  
                        </p:dataTable>
```

Screenshot web Page generated:

[image]

What should I do? I use jsf 2.2 and Primefaces 5.1

Comment: _"What should I do?"_: Start by trying the latest version of PF (mentioning the version you use is also important btw) and look in the issue list for known issues.

Comment: I'm using Primefaces 5.1...

Comment: Thanks, but what about the other 2 questions?

Comment: Hi Kukeltje! First of all thanks by suggestions. I looked at the issues tracker and the changelog(version 5.2) and did not found solution of this problem. I upgraded the version primefaces to 5.2 and the problem persists, so I created a new issue:  [link] (https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/391)

Comment: there is at least version primefaces 6.1

Comment: did you already use the version 6.1 and checked of this is solved @MitchBroadhead?